# Fade in & out content with jquery address (ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-address

How'd I go about making the content already loaded fade out once the new content has loaded, then this new content fade in.

I'm using jquery address to try and achieve this, if its easier/better with another plugin please suggest one :-)

The code I have is as follows:

```
    function loadURL(url) {
        console.log("loadURL: " + url);
        $("#content").load(url);
    }

    $.address.init(function(event) {
        console.log("init: " + $('[rel=address:' + event.value + ']').attr('href'));
    }).change(function(event) {
        $("#content").load($('[rel=address:' + event.value + ']').attr('href'));
        console.log("change");
    })

    $('a').click(function(){
        loadURL($(this).attr('href'));
        $("#content").hide();
        $("#content").fadeIn();
    });
```

I did try and think that I could maybe create a loader div, that I'd fade in over the top rather than fading out the content, but I really don't know where to go with it.

At the moment the content fade's in, and once you click the other link it changes to the new content, also fading it in, but I don't know how I'd make it fade out, before the new content fades in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: if you want one to fade out *at the same time as* the other fades in, you'll need two separate divs.

Comment: That could be an option, but ideally I'd like the content in the div, or the whole div to fade out, and then the new one to fade in with the new content, if that makes any sense

Comment: that makes total sense. then you need to fade out the div, change the content & then fade the div in again - which seems to be what you're doing. where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: It does what it should, just not in the correct way haha.

It basically does this: 
Hide new data loaded in
Fade in new data
--
But instead of fading out previous data it just disappears, i need to fade out the old data if the link has been pressed to load the new data in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qPVMZ/) is what you are looking for.   I use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$('#b').click(function(){
    $.ajax({

      //i had to create another test fiddle to overcome the 'same origin' issues
      url: 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/K6YPD/show/',
      success: function(data) {             

          //we have the data now
          $('#content').fadeOut(1500, function() {
            //this is a callback once the element has finished hiding

              //populate the div with whatever was returned from the ajax call
              $('#content').html(stripHTML(data));
              //fade in with new content
              $("#content").fadeIn(1500);
          });
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: As a matter of efficiency, you can eliminate one jQuery selector by combining two lines into one like this: `$('#content').html(stripHTML(data)).fadeIn(1500);`  It's easier to see what's happening in my example, but this line is faster.